# SFTP in Sublime Text 3 not working

Tags: ftp, sftp, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm having the strangest problem.

On a fresh Sublime Text 3 installation, I'm trying to get SFTP (wbond) to function.

I've tried following the documentation, but can't get it to work. I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WU_aZ0gZABU) to a tee, but for some reason my installation acts differently to the same input.

I've installed `package manager`, `sidebar enhancements` and `SFTP` from wbond.

In the linked Youtube video, when he goes to "browse" an FTP server and there isn't one setup, it jumps to a new file automatically where he can input his data. Mine just pastes the content of this file directly into the document I'm in.

If I create a new document, go `File > SFTP/FTP > Setup Server...` and input my FTP data (that works perfectly fine in clients such as Filezilla) and save, nothing happens.

If, afterwards, I go `File > SFTP/FTP > Browse Server...` I get a popup asking me to setup a new server, even though I just did.

I feel like I'm not seeing the forest for the trees here, and I'm probably missing something simple.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

File turns out needs to be saved in

> %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/User/sftp_servers/

folder.

It can be accessed in Sublime 3 clicking Preferences->Browse packages...

Comment: Which file? the settings file?